# onclick get the project id and send it to back.php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to display the details of projects in database and and allow admins to them delete them.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php
    include 'dbc.php';
    $query=mysql_query("select * from pro1");
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo '<span>'.$result['name'].'</span>'.'<a href="#" id='.$result['pro_id'].' onclick="delet(this.id);">delet</a>'.'<br/>';
    }
?>       
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>test10</span><a href="#" id=10 onclick="delet(this.id);">delet</a>    

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function delete(proid){
                //alert(proid);
                $.post("back.php",{
                    proid:proid
                },function(data){
                    alert(data);
                });
        });//ready func end
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

I'm getting the `proid` from db... now I need to send the id with ajax.
The loop output will be something like this:

```
<span>test10</span>
 <a href="#" id=10 onclick="delete(this.id);">delete</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

There is **missing** one **closing bracket** for the function.

Note: The function must not be wrapped to be executed on load, otherwise it **won't** be accessible !

---

## Solution

[(JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/WjXDf/1/)

### Javascript/jQuery

```
    function delet(proid){
        //alert(proid);
        $.post("back.php",{
            proid:proid
        },function(data){
            alert(data);
        });
    } /*This one here */
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `delet` function out of the `document.ready` wrapper. It can't be accessed because it's out of scope:

```
            // no $(document).ready()
            function delet(proid){
                $.post("back.php",{
                    proid:proid
                },function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }); // <-- this was missing
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want like this

JQuery :-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    function delete(proid)
    {
       $.ajax({
           url: 'back.php',
           type: "get",
           data:'id='+ proid,
           success: function (response) {
              alert(data);
           }

        });      
    }
});
```

PHP:-

```
<?php
    include 'dbc.php';

    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $sql=mysql_query("DELETE FROM pro1 WHERE pro_id='$id'");

    if($sql)
       echo "Deleted Succesfully<br>";

    else
       echo "Problem to delete :(<br>";

    $query=mysql_query("select * from pro1");
    while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo '<span>'.$result['name'].'</span>'.'<a href="#" id='.$result['pro_id'].' onclick="delet(this.id);">delet</a>'.'<br/>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I may be wrong as i am not an expert in PHP or JQUERY. just let me know plz.

Comment: This code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.  Please check out this question for advice on how to make your php code more secure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @sharif Also note that `mysql` is *deprecated* in latest PHP versions. You'll want to use `mysqli` or `PDO` statements for regular `MySQL` queries.